# How to remove text area border (outline) when focused on with knockoutJs css binding?

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have a text area which I want to remove outline glow on focus with knockout css/attr binding and hasFocus binding. But the outline glow is not resetting on focus.
 Thank you in advance.

```js
var viewModel = {
  isFocus: ko.observable(false),
  outlineglow: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.isFocus.subscribe(function(focus) {
  if (focus) {
    viewModel.outlineglow("none");
  }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<textarea data-bind="hasFocus: isFocus, attr: { 'focus:outline': outlineglow }"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`style`**](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) binding to set the `outline` based on the `isFocus` observable:

```js
var viewModel = {
  isFocus: ko.observable(true)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<textarea data-bind="hasFocus: isFocus, style: { outline:  isFocus() ? 'none' : '1px dashed red'}"> </textarea>
```

If you want to apply a lot of `style` on focus, you can bind a `class` using the [`css`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding:

```js
var viewModel = {
  isFocus: ko.observable(true)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.focused {
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-color: red;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<textarea data-bind="hasFocus: isFocus, css: { focused:  isFocus() }"> </textarea>
```